# ordering nodes for a 2D element

Tags: algorithm, nodes

I have four nodes in a 3D space
A(x1,y1,z1), B(x2,y2,z2), C(x3,y3,z3) and D(x4,y4,z4)

Now, I want to use these four nodes to form a convex quadrilateral element, so how do you order the nodes as counter-clockwise?

Comment: Or, not care about the clockwise, just make sure that no cross between line AB  and line CD

Comment: Search for "segment-segment intersection" or look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/563275/1307866)

Comment: Cleaer up grammar (the question is answerable as is)

Comment: A general solution in two dimensions is ordering the points according to direction to average. If you are certain the nodes are of a 2D element, you could translate the coordinates to the plane and do that.

Comment: Are the four points _guaranteed_ to form a valid quad (given the right order)? That is, are all in the same plane? And are they always convex quads? (I think otherwise the problem is ill-defined) If the answers are yes, I _think_ you can just compute the pairwise distances and make sure that the furthest pair is not contiguous.

Comment: Thank you all. What I am doing is to constructing plane element for finite element method. For this kind of problem,  a more suitable method is to predefine the node order which can be then used to order the new node set.